# Error when starting hbase shell in windows 10

Tags: hadoop

C:\hadoop-3.2.1\hbase\bin>hbase shell
This file has been superceded by packaging our ruby files into a jar
and using jruby's bootstrapping to invoke them. If you need to
source this file fo some reason it is now named 'jar-bootstrap.rb' and is
located in the root of the file hbase-shell.jar and in the source tree at
'hbase-shell/src/main/ruby'.

Answer (score 1):

I think this behaviour can be seen from Hbase Version 2.X.
If you just want to playaround you can use Hbase 1.4.9 .

Comment: why we want to use older version when stable latest version available? Please provide answer that make sense or suggest downgrading.